# Can I use OSSEC in a home LAN to monitor for intrusion and malwares?

Tags: linux, windows, malware, ossec

I'm not quite sure I understand what OSSEC does. But after *HiddenWasp*, I would like to make sure my Windows and Linux machines in my home are safe. (And harden my VPS)

Does OSSEC support antimalware scanning/detection ?

I couldn't find anything in the docs about that except some log files from ClamAV for example.

There is a [slide from 2014](https://www.slideshare.net/SantiagoBassett/malware-detection-with-ossec-hids-osseccon-2014) which suggest using dionaea, maltrieve and Cuckoo for malware detection... but not much information seems to be available on the internet and I feel like I'm wasting my time. Am I?

Comment: I doubt there's information about [OSSEC](https://www.ossec.net/docs/) on the Internet.

Comment: I read it before asking, since I'm asking you must then ask yourself if I found something in the docs about the question being asked, but thanks for wasting your time.